# Receivers event for if anything changed in the web

Tags: 2013

i am looking for if there is any receivers event as if anything changed in web, it triggers, it includes custom webparts and user controls

Comment: You mean you need to have a server-side event to catch if any user control or Web Part is added? You can do it within the user control or Web Part isn't it?

Comment: What is it you want the event receivers to do, and where? Please edit your answer and explain further.

Answer (score 1):

There are several event receivers you can capture:

web, list, field, item  creation and deletion 
On item level you can also capture updates, check-ins, ...

When you add a web-part to a page, the page is actually an item that needs to be saved. So you can capture it with the "item updated" event-receiver. 
The exact details of what happened on the page will not be available in the event receiver.

A control is added/deployed by a feature or placed inside a (custom) master page or page layout.

Be careful with implementing this kind of behavior. Sounds like a brilliant recipe for creating performance issues. :-)